# Progress bar, блокирование страницы

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте, у меня есть функция для некоторых подсчетов, которая должна выполниться много раз. Пользователь вводит количество итераций, нажимает на кнопку и начинается выполнение. Во время выполнения, прогресс бар должен отображать какая часть итераций уже выполнена.
Я столкнулся с проблемой что при входе в функцию страница блокируется и можно увидеть лишь конечный результат выполнения (прогресс сразу с 0 на 100%).
Необходимо сделать так: нажатие на кнопку, функция выполняется один раз, данные обновляются, функция выполняется опять и так до конца.

Comment: Добавьте ваш код

Comment: http://angels737site.esy.es/  выложил на хостинг

Comment: Там слишком много кода, но суть в том, что при начале выполнения страница зависает, и данные не обновляются до самого конца выполнения, хотя в коде значения обновляются после каждой итерации.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), должно помочь, они выполняются в другом потоке, если конечно не важны старые браузеры.

Answer (score 2):

Код крайне неоптимально написан, в т.ч. вычислительная часть, однако начните с того, что вытащите из всех циклов получение элементов по id, а затем оберните критичные вызовы, а именно `iterate()` в `setTimeout` с задержкой `0`, возможно дальнейшей оптимизации удастся избежать.  Как уже упомянули в комментариях, простым неалгоритмическим путём оптимизации являются WebWorkers. Но всё-таки ещё попробуйте подумать, какие вычисления избыточны и их очевидно можно провести заранее, вне основного цикла или другим способом упростить.